# Method for getting data into game with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm about to work on a Objective-C game projects, and I'm curious to what's the options for getting constant data into the game. I've worked for many years as a Flash dev and in Flash I would just simply setup a class file and put in it objects like this...

```
static var arrowData:Object = {
                elementType:"projectile",name:"arrow",sourceType:"library", imgSource:"arrow", imageSourceSub:"",cellsX:1, cellsY:1,    
                bounderyType:"none",bounderyLeft:0,bounderyRight:1200, bounderyTop:80, bounderyBottom:580,
                position:{rotateToDir:false,positionType:"movieclip", randomX:false, randomY:false, endRandomX:600, endRandomY:400, startX:0, startY:0},
                visual:{imgLabel1:"", imgNumFrames1:15,imgFramesLoop1:true,runOnFrame1:0,runOnFrameFN1:"",runOnLastFN1:""},
                movement:{moveType:"arc", maxDistance:400, atTarget:"remove", target:"mouse", targetData1:"mouseX", targetData2:"none"},            
                physical:{physData:"spritesLayer"},
                interactive:{interactionType:"rect", removeOnInteraction:true, interactionResult:"ingame", interactionData1:"badGuysArray", interactionData2:"projectileCollision"},
                character:{damage:10}
            };
```

I've Objects inside Objects, but there doesn't seem to be any clear way to do the same with Objective-C, so my questions are...

1. Is there any way to do the same as the above in Objective-C?
2. What are the other methods for getting data into Objective-C? XML?
3. How do iOS game devs usually store their constant game data?
4. I'm going to be using the parse hosting service with this project, are there
   options for using that to store the data and loading it from there?

Comment: Property lists (plists) or JSON are fairly common. Plists are particularly easy because you can use `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:...]]]`.

Comment: That format appears to be very close to JSON.  JSON is very easily read into a structure of NSDictionaries and NSArrays, using any of several tools.  (The later versions of iOS have a JSON reader built in, while for earlier versions you can use an open source module.)  (XML used to be the common way to feed in "static" data, but JSON has take over since it's so much simpler and more efficient.)

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by @tc touched on, the common way to maintain groups of related info is in NSDictionaries (or their mutable cousins). Dictionaries can also nest. You have two ways to save these easily: as plists per comment or in the 'defaults' system. The latter is more restrictive on the types of data it stores. Apple also has a class that will convert between JSON and native objects. I have no experience with question 4 - hope others can answer that.

Comment: JSON looks very similar to what I already have but there doesn't seem to be any clear way to generate JSON date directly, say by creating a .txt file in xcode and then having xcode read that in.

Comment: Well, you can create all your objects as dictionaries, arrays, and strings - then use the NSJSON.. class to convert it to JSON for you. But this would seem to make your software more complex not less. I'd bite the bullet, use the standard iOS facilities (you have to learn them someday anyway), and only revert to JSON as needed to converse with the outside world.